# UITableView row height

Tags: uitableview

I have a subclass of a UITableViewCell. Its got some additional items on it for a total of 3 labels and up to 2 buttons. When creating the call in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I call a method `resizeToFitSubviews` that resizes labels, and moves buttons around to the right position, it will remove unused buttons, etc. At this point I know the final height of the cell.

I tried to store the height in a `NSMutableArray` in the `UITableViewController` so I could return it in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` call but for some reason `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. And it seams its only called once as far as I can tell.

How do I go about knowing the height, when the cell isn't yet created?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to know a better solution to this, but I think after you calculate the height of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have to let the table know to reload the data in the cell, so then you get to tell it the correct height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Of course you should make sure that you don't loop yourself by doing it again when you are in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` after the reload. Sucky, but works.